# Do I need to have Imploding Kittens to use Streaking Kittens?

Tags: expansions, exploding-kittens

The first expansion to *Exploding Kittens* is of course *Imploding Kittens*. The second expansion is *Streaking Kittens*.

Can I use *Streaking Kittens* with *Exploding Kittens* without throwing *Imploding Kittens* into the mix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the base game with only the second expansion, as none of the cards in the Streaking Kittens expansion requires anything from the Imploding Kittens pack.